# Vundle Install Plugin YCM failed, The remote end hung up unexpectedly, index-pack failed

Tags: vundle, youcompleteme

```
   git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.gi
   Cloning into '/Users/xxxxxx/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe'...           
   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200                      
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly                         
   fatal: early EOF                                                   
   fatal: index-pack failed
```

I'm using vundle installing YCM, but after a very long time, the YCM plugin installation always ends up error in installation, above is what I got in the vundle installation log.

I use vundle installed other plugins without any issue and use git clone other repositories without any issue, so it's not a git connection issue

Comment: You may try some proxy.